# Read file with strings and integers in matlab

Tags: file, matlab, file-io, newline

I have to read a file in Matlab that looks like this:

> D:\Classified\positive-videos\vid.avi 163 3 14 32 54 79 105 130 155 202 216 224 238 250 262 288 288 322 357 369 381 438 457 478 499 525 551
>   D:\Classified\positive-videos\vid2.avi 163 3 14 32 54 79 105 130 155 202 216 224 238 250 262 288 288 322 357 369 381 438 457 478 499 525 551

There are many such lines separated by newline. I need to read it such that: I discard path of video name and first integer(eg 163 in first line) and read rest all the numbers in an array till new line occurs. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
fid = fopen('test1.txt','r');
my_line = fgetl(fid);
while(my_line ~= -1)
    my_array = regexp(my_line,' ','split');
    my_line = fgetl(fid);
    disp(my_array(3:end));
end
fclose(fid);
```

This would give you:

```
ans = 

  Columns 1 through 11

    '3'    '14'    '32'    '54'    '79'    '105'    '130'    '155'    '202'    '216'    '224'

  Columns 12 through 22

    '238'    '250'    '262'    '288'    '288'    '322'    '357'    '369'    '381'    '438'    '457'

  Columns 23 through 26

    '478'    '499'    '525'    '551'


ans = 

  Columns 1 through 11

    '3'    '14'    '32'    '54'    '79'    '105'    '130'    '155'    '202'    '216'    '224'

  Columns 12 through 22

    '238'    '250'    '262'    '288'    '288'    '322'    '357'    '369'    '381'    '438'    '457'

  Columns 23 through 26

    '478'    '499'    '525'    '551'
```

### EDIT

For a numeric matrix result you can change it as:

```
clear;
close;
clc;

fid = fopen('test1.txt','r');
my_line = fgetl(fid);
my_array = regexp(my_line,' ','split');
my_matrix = zeros(0, numel(my_array(3:end)));
ii = 1;
while(my_line ~= -1)
    my_array = regexp(my_line,' ','split');
    my_line = fgetl(fid);
    my_matrix = [my_matrix;zeros(1,size(my_matrix,2))];
    for jj=1:numel(my_array(3:end))
        my_matrix(ii,jj) = str2num(cell2mat(my_array(jj+2)));
    end
    ii = ii + 1;
end
fclose(fid);
```

This would yeild:

```
my_matrix =

     3    14    32    54    79   105   130   155   202   216   224   238   250   262   288   288   322   357   369   381   438   457   478   499   525   551
     3    14    32    54    79   105   130   155   202   216   224   238   250   262   288   288   322   357   369   381   438   457   478   499   525   551
```

Comment: @RoneyMichael I have a gripe your solution, it seems way too complicated than it should be.

Comment: @EitanT: I felt the same too in fact.. I'm not too familiar with cell arrays; I'd be grateful for a better one.

Comment: @RoneyMichael See fpe's answer.

Answer (score 2):

A way easier method follows up:

```
fid = importdata(filename)
results = fid.data;
```

Ad maiora.

**EDIT**

Since you wanna discard the first value after the string, you will have to call

```
res = fid.data(:,2:end);
```

instead of `results`.

Comment: In it's current form, this doesn't import the numbers as individual values, but as one long string.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your point. `fid` is stored in a `structure` and data is a matrix indeed. Could you explain me a little more what you meant?

Comment: I get that `importdata` retrieves each line as a long without splitting it into space delimited values.